# Два поля TextFormField наподобие конвертера в две стороны

Tags: flutter, dart

Не могу разобраться как осуществить взаимодействие между двумя TextFormField. Требуется (для примера): вводя число в первом поле, отображать утроенное значение первого поля во втором, и наоборот - вводя во второе поле число, отображать поделенное на три значение второго поля.
Проблема в том, что поля либо рекурсивно друг друга изменяют, либо происходит что-то совсем непонятное. Просто отобразить текст из одного поля в другое и наоборот - все получается. Но при вычислениях все время какие-то ошибки. Может я неправильно работаю с числами? Закомментировано то, что приводит к ошибкам.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget
{
  MyPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  _pageState createState() => _pageState();
}

class _pageState extends State<MyPage>
{
  final myController1 = TextEditingController();
  final myController2 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Начинаем слушать изменения.
    myController1.addListener(() => _listener('textField1'));
    myController2.addListener(() => _listener('textField2'));
  }

  //Слушатель
  void _listener(String textField) {
    switch (textField) {
      case ('textField1'):
        myController2.value = TextEditingValue(
          //---!!!---
          //text: (int.parse(myController1.text) * 3).toString(),
          text: myController1.text,
          selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
            TextPosition(offset: myController1.text.length),
          ),
        );
        break;
      case ('textField2'):
        myController1.value = TextEditingValue(
          //---!!!---
          //text: (int.parse(myController2.text) / 3).toString(),
          text: myController2.text,
          selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
            TextPosition(offset: myController2.text.length),
          ),
        );
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController1.dispose();
    myController2.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              controller: myController1,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              controller: myController2,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас проблема в том что, каждый раз каждый TextEditingController реагировал на изменения (своеобразная рекурсия происходила). Вот простое решение как можно сделать по другому:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<MyPage> {
  late final myController1 = TextEditingController();
  late final myController2 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController1.dispose();
    myController2.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              controller: myController1,
              onChanged: (String s) {
                if (s.isEmpty) {
                  myController2.text = '';
                } else {
                  myController2.text = (int.parse(s) * 3).toString();
                }
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              controller: myController2,
              onChanged: (String s) {
                if (s.isEmpty) {
                  myController1.text = '';
                } else {
                  myController1.text = (int.parse(s) / 3).toString();
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я основывалась на этой статье https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes. Насколько я поняла, есть два подхода - onChanged и TextEditingController, и что последнему нужен слушатель. А вот такого варианта симбиоза я нигде не встречала. Спасибо, Вы очень помогли!

Comment: Если я ответил на вопрос, его можно отметить как правильным (галочка под стрелками слева от ответа).

Comment: Хорошо, извините, я здесь недавно. Я поставила галочку. Спасибо!